# How to process word similarity and categorize a group of words to a single word

Tags: machine-learning, classification, fuzzy-classification

Am new in this area and have been searching for some time only to find multiple different possible approaches but nothing concrete.

If I have a wordlist of say; `email_addr`, `email`, `email_address`, `address` or more dissimilarly `first`, `first_name`, `firstName`, `christianName`, `christian_name`, `name`. What would be the most suitable approach to classify each of those lists to a single word, like `email` or `givenName` respectively?

I've seen some articles proposing; Levenstein, fuzzy matching, difference algorithm, support vector machines of which I don't think any quite satisfy the requirement, unless I am missing something.

Would appreciate any links or direction to research.

Essentially, the objective is to categorize all column names in a data set so I can map them to a method for each type of column to generate mock data.

Comment: Hey, Did you find any solution or approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. "Cluster" words in a single list to find the "closest" matches. This could be useful since in `email_addr`, `email`, `email_address`, `address` the word `address` could be seen as an "outlier". You can use [affinity propagation to cluster words](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups) if needed. However, I think this step is only needed if there is a lot of "variance" in the words.
2. Once you have an okay list of words such as `email_addr`, `email`, `email_address`, you can apply a *pairwise* [levenshtein distance](https://pypi.org/project/Distance/) to each word pair and pick the $n$ "closest" matches ("pairs"). With three words (as above), keeping the two closest matches would likely yield: `email_addr`, `email_address`.
3. Keep as a "truth" the common parts of the $n$ top matches, which could be `email_addr` or simply `email` in this case.

I have a [similar problem](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/108223/unsupervized-latent-truth-discovery-on-text-data) in the moment and would apprechiatre any insights from your experiance.

Comment: For the examples given I would like all words in the list to "map to" a given word/category, with weight might also be necessary, as `address` could also be a street address within a different context.